# Calculates the Kevin Bacon number of an actor in graph

Tags: python, list, function, graph, queue

I have made `Queue` Class and `Graph` classes

1st: Program a function

```
kevin_bacon_number(moviegraph, actor)
```

that calculates the Kevin Bacon number of an actor in your graph.

Testing: The code

```
g = Graph('movies.txt', False, '/')
kevin_bacon_number(g, 'De Niro, Robert')
```

should result in 1 (they were both in the same movie) and 2nd.

Program a function

```
actors_with_number(moviegraph, number)
```

That calculates the list of actors that have number as Kevin Bacon number.

Testing: The code

```
g = Graph('movies.txt', False, '/')
actors_with_number(g, 0)
```

should result in `Bacon, Kevin`. and `'De Niro, Robert'` in `actors_with_number(g, 1)` should be `True`.

```
class Queue:

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Construct Queue object self as an empty Queue object.

    def __init__(self):
        self._first = None  # Reference to first _Node
        self._last = None   # Reference to last _Node
        self._length = 0    # Number of items

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Return True if self is empty, and False otherwise.

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._first is None

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Add item to the end of self.

    def enqueue(self, item):
        oldLast = self._last
        self._last = _Node(item, None)
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._first = self._last
        else:
            oldLast.next = self._last
        self._length += 1

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Remove the first item of self and return it.

    def dequeue(self):
        item = self._first.item
        self._first = self._first.next
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._last = None
        self._length -= 1
        return item

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Return the number of items in self.

    def __len__(self):
        return self._length

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Return a string representation of self.

    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        cur = self._first
        while cur is not None:
            s += str(cur.item) + ' '
            cur = cur.next
        return s

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A `_Node` object references an `item` and a `next _Node` object.
A `Queue` object is composed of `_Node` objects.

```
class _Node:
    def __init__(self, item, next):
        self.item = item  # Reference to an item
        self.next = next  # Reference to the next _Node object
```

```
class Graph:

    # Construct a new Graph object. If a filename is specified,
    # populate the Graph object by reading data from the specified
    # file with the specified delimiter.
    # For directed graphs the argument directed should get value True
    def __init__(self,  filename=None, directed=False, delimiter=None):
        self._directed = directed
        self._e = 0
        self._adj = dict()
        if filename is not None:
            f = open(filename, 'r')
            lines = f.read().split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                names = line.split(delimiter)
                for i in range(1, len(names)):
                    self.addEdge(names[0], names[i])
            line = ''
                
    # Add an edge to self between vertex v and vertex w.
    def addEdge(self, v, w):
        if not self.hasVertex(v): self._adj[v] = set()
        if not self.hasVertex(w): self._adj[w] = set()
        if not self.hasEdge(v, w):
            self._e += 1
            self._adj[v].add(w)
            if not self._directed: self._adj[w].add(v)
            
    # Return an iterable collection containing all neighbors of
    # vertex v in self.
    def adjacentTo(self, v):
        return iter(self._adj[v])
    
    # Return an iterable collection of all vertices in self.
    def vertices(self):
        return iter(self._adj)

    # Return True if vertex v is in self, and False otherwise.
    def hasVertex(self, v):
        return v in self._adj

    # Return True if v-w is an edge in self, and False otherwise.
    def hasEdge(self, v, w):
        return w in self._adj[v]
    
    # Return the number of vertices in self.
    def countV(self):
        return len(self._adj)
    
    # Return the number of edges in self.
    def countE(self):
        return self._e
    
    # Return the degree of vertex v of self.
    def degree(self, v):
        return len(self._adj[v])

    # Return a string representation of self.
    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        for v in self.vertices():
            s += v + '  '
            for w in self.adjacentTo(v):
                s += w + ' '
            s += '\n'
        return s
```

Comment: Can you post `movies.txt` ?

Comment: What is your question?